# in typescript, how to infer the parameter type from the argument type of the 2nd function call in a curried function

Tags: typescript

if i have a function

```
const g = f => p => f(p)
g(x => x + 3)(5)
```

How do I type 'g' so that the type of x can be inferred from the argument '5'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this.. you are asking TS to go backwards in inference, and it doesn't do that.

Comment: Yeah, `g` is typed like `const g = <T, U>(f: (x: T) => U) => (p: T) => f(p)` but the contextual typing of `x` in `x=>x+3` given `5` is likely beyond the scope of what the compiler can do.  Left-to-right and earlier-to-later inference is more reliable.

Comment: I don't know the actual implementation of typescript, but "going backwards" or "right-to-left" doesn't sound too much more difficult than "left-to-right" since after parsing the code into ast, you got everything at hand

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are describing it, it's impossible as your factory `g` might creat different functions as `const func = g(x => x + 3);` may be used as `func('asdad') // returns 'asdad3'` and `func(5) // returns 8`. You cannot infer the type from usage this way as there are endless possibilities of usage. You have to apriori set the type of the `x` thus deciding whether it's gonna be `func('asda')` or `func(5)`.

Comment: "You cannot infer the type from usage this way as there are endless possibilities of usage", that's exactly why we need typescript to 'infer' the type from usage. Before we provide the argument 5 or 'asda', of cause typescript cannot do anything, but as long as it sees it, it's pretty clear what that type is. So to me this is just a lack of feature in typescript